# Winsock UDP broadcast packets not sent

Tags: c++, windows, udp, winsock2

I'm encountering a strange issue using winsock when multiple network adapters are active but then one is disconnected.

This is the basic scenario:

1. Wifi and Ethernet are active and connected
2. Launch app, send UDP broadcast and receive response
3. Unplug Ethernet, restart app and try to send again - Nothing is sent (Wireshark shows nothing, seems Windows is dropping them before they get to NIC?)
4. Disable the disconnected Ethernet adapter and try again - sends fine over Wifi and gets response.

Now this is a very specific scenario but I believe it's happening in other cases, this is just the only way I know to reproduce it every time.

The following is a code snippet of the UDP send, for this example assume dstAddrStr is 192.168.1.255

```
struct sockaddr_in sa_remote;
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Error creating socket: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
}

int enable = 1;
if ((setsockopt(sock,
    SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char*)&enable, sizeof(enable))) == -1) {
    printf("Error enabling broadcasts: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
}

const MIB_IPADDRROW & row = iptbl->table[i];
uint32 ipAddr = ntohl(row.dwAddr);
uint32 netmask = ntohl(row.dwMask);
uint32 baddr = ipAddr & netmask;
if (row.dwBCastAddr) baddr |= ~netmask;

char dstAddrStr[32];  Inet_NtoA(baddr, dstAddrStr);

memset(&sa_remote, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
sa_remote.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa_remote.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(dstAddrStr);
sa_remote.sin_port = htons(_DST_PORT);


if (sendto(sock, dpString, strlen(dpString), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sa_remote, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0){
    printf("UDP send error Error: %ld", WSAGetLastError());
    break;
}
```

Comment: You should probably be using `dwBCastAddr`, not trying to compute the broadcast address, depending on how `iptbl` was populated.

Comment: Wouldn't work, a row is populated with the following http://i.imgur.com/c5nA1jw.png